# Finding the sum of this series $\sum (\alpha x)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm looking for help on how to find the sum and interval of convergence of this series (Starts at 0 and goes to infinity). Now this one is giving me trouble because I've never seen a series with the "α" before. I was thinking maybe I could start by comparing with $\sum x^n$ which has the sum of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but I am not sure.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(\alpha x)^n, \alpha>0$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about $1/(1-\alpha x)$ ?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo thats only true for $ |\alpha x|<1$

Comment: Is there more information we know about the numbers in this question?

Comment: Yeah, as in @daniels_pa 's answer, note that it is a geometric series, so you can use the usual formulas for $S_∞$

Answer (score 2):

Yes the sum you wrote

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n
$$

Converges for $|x|<1$

Same can be applied here.
For $|\alpha x|<1$ we have that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\alpha x)^n = \frac{1}{1-\alpha x}
$$

So it converges when $-1<\alpha x<1$ . There we have

For
$\alpha=0$, converges $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
$\alpha>0$, converges $\forall x\in (-\frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\alpha})$
$\alpha<0$, converges $\forall x\in (\frac{1}{\alpha},-\frac{1}{\alpha})$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have to be honest though, I don't know what the upside-down A or the 'E' symbols mean. My math history has been: College Algebra > Trig > Pre-cal > Cal1 > Cal2.

Comment: Upside-down A means for all 
and the 'E' symbol or '$\in$' means belongs to as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Membership)

Comment: Just an added note that may help you understand, the reason why this works is a simple substitution with $y = \alpha x$ and then the sum @daniels_pa wrote goes to $\frac{1}{1-y} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha x} $. You may want to write this in your formal proof as an intermediate step just for clarity.